# Stop both BroadcastReceiver and Service in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service

How do I exactly stops a Service in Broadcast receiver? I am using a SMS Received broadcast receiver.

I am using

```
context.stopService(new Intent(this, CallService.class));
```

where "CallService" is my service, yet I am receiving

```
The constructor Intent(SMSReceiver, Class<CallService>) is undefined
```

and the Quick Fix is to `remove the arguments to match 'Intent()'`

Am I doing something wrong here?

---

To stop the broadcast receiver, all I have to do is
`context.unregisterReceiver(SMSReceiver.this);`
That's all? Do I have to do onDestroy or anything?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `context` instead of `this` to instantiate Intent like below

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, CallService.class));
```

The unregister part is correct.

Comment: Wow! This doesn't generate any error, but I will have a go at the compiled app soon. But do you mind explaining, why do we use `context` this time round, and not `this`?

Comment: Intent requires a context object as the first parameter, but BroadcastReciever(unlike activity and service) does not extend a context object. So you cannot use this